# Creating a square in directx

Tags: c++, directx

I am currently trying to learn the basics of directX and i need some simple help.

I've made a triangle that will print out without any problems what so ever but when i try to add another corner to that triangle to make it a square it wont work. I've tried to change the order that i create the corners but this one makes the most sense and does not work. I'd be so happy if someone could look at it and tell me what i am doing wrong. Thanks!!

```
void CreateTriangleData()
{
    struct TriangleVertex
    {
        float x, y, z;
        float r, g, b;
    };

    TriangleVertex triangleVertices[4] =
    {
        0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,      //v1
        1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,                    //v1 color

        -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,     //v2
        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,                    //v2 color

        0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,       //v0 pos
        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,                   //v0 color

        -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.0f,      //v3
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc;
    memset(&bufferDesc, 0, sizeof(bufferDesc));
    bufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(triangleVertices);

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA data;
    data.pSysMem = triangleVertices;
    gDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, &data, &gVertexBuffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use indexing, i.e. you are drawing with [`Draw()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), rather than [`DrawIndexed()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476409%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you should put into vertex buffer all the vertices that contribute to both triangles (i.e. 6 vertices). If you are drawing a quad, there will be two pairs of duplicate vertices.

In order to avoid duplication one can use index buffer.

Typical gotcha: You should preserve winding order of vertices in vertex buffer in order your triangles to be visible (See: [Back-face culling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-face_culling))

[image]

See also:

- [MSDN - Introduction to Buffers in Direct3D 11](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476898%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [MSDN - How to: Create an Index Buffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your topology to make it work.

You are using only vertex buffer so you need to you TRIANGLESTRIP Topology in case of 4 vertices and TRIANGLELIST in case of 6 vertices. 
TRIANGLESTRIP will make one triangle from vertices 1,2 and 3 and second triangle from 3,4 and 1 vertex, both of these triangles becomes a rectangle.
TRIANGLELIST will make one triangle from vertices 1,2 and 3 and second from 4,5 and 6, in this case you will need to give two more vertices.

Different type of topologies are listed here 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728726(v=vs.85).aspx

Second option is to use Index buffer, instead of vertex buffer which is explained here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx